# How to send POST request to relative URL with RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

How can I send a `POST` request to the application itself?

If I just send a relative post request: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute`.

```
@RestController
public class TestServlet {
    @RequestMapping("value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void test() {
        String relativeUrl = "/posting"; //TODO how to generate like "localhost:8080/app/posting"?
        new RestTemplate().postForLocation(relativeUrl, null);
    }
}
```

So using the example above, how can I prefix the url with the absolute server url path `localhost:8080/app`? I have to find the path dynamically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a neat way that basically automates the task using `ServletUriComponentsBuilder`:

```
@RequestMapping("value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void test(HttpServletRequest req) {
    UriComponents url = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromServletMapping(req).path("/posting").build();
        new RestTemplate().postForLocation(url.toString(), null);
    }
```

Comment: I'm curious, why would you want to make a request to a server from inside the server? Typically a controller will be backed by a service, so why don't you just call this service directly ?

Comment: spring has a feature for hot reloading `application.properties` values. This can be achieved by using the `@RefreshScope` on classes that contain `@Value` properties. Unfortunately spring requires a `POST` request to `<app-path>/refresh`. Und does not support simple `GET` browser request on that url. So I'm providing a simple GET and internally send the POST.

Comment: Ahh, then I would qualify you solution as a hack ;) see my answer below

Comment: I'm accepting my anwer as the initial question was about how to send relative POST requests. Anysways for my root problem the correct solution would be using the `RefreshEndpoint.refresh()`.

Answer (score 8):

You can rewrite your method like below.

```
@RequestMapping("value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void test(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
    String relativeUrl = url+"/posting"; 
    new RestTemplate().postForLocation(relativeUrl, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refresh application.properties, you should AutoWire the RefreshScope into you controller, and call it explicitly, it make it much easier to see what it going on.
[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35341684/changing-spring-boot-properties-programmatically)

```
@Autowired
public RefreshScope refreshScope;

refreshScope.refreshAll();
```

Comment: It might be even better to inject `RefreshEndpoint` and call `.refresh()`, as this is exactly what the POST request does.